# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation eclipselink 2.7.12 on EAP 7.4

Tags: java, eclipselink, jboss7.x

I am getting the following error when deploy my application using eclipselink 2.7.12 on EAP 7.4.
Do you have an idea what is the cause ?

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:673)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1233)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.persistenceprovider.PersistenceProviderLoader.loadProviderModuleByName(PersistenceProviderLoader.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:994)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.addPuService(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:266)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.handleEarDeployment(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:228)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:135)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.5.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.13.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider: when selecting method 'javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil javax.persistence
.spi.PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()' the class loader 'javax.persistence.api@2.2.3.redhat-00001' @712a71c1 for super interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider, and the class loader 'org.eclipse.persistence@2.7.12.v2
0230209-e5c4074ef3' @2ba8c1fd of the selected method's class, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider have different Class objects for the type javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil used in the signature (javax.persistence.spi.
PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader 'javax.persistence.api@2.2.3.redhat-00001' @712a71c1, parent loader 'app'; org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider is in unnamed module of loader 'org.eclipse.persistence@2.
7.12.v20230209-e5c4074ef3' @2ba8c1fd, parent loader 'app')
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:660)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:657)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:668)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: How did you install EclipseLink? By default JBoss EAP uses Hibernate as its JPA implementation.